# Not receiving mail notification

Tags: email, notification, postfix, mail, nagios3

I recently installed Nagios Core 4.4.3, after a while I wanted to set up mail notification, I installed Postfix (GMAIL SMTP Config) and the config seems to be fine as I tried to send some mails but now for nagios notification the nagios.log is showing this error, any advices please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out, I changed the path in nagios commands.cfg and it's working now, you can now close this thread